# Why am I receiving this "pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError"?

Tags: python, 22.04, python3, rabbitmq

I have been trying to run a file named "send.py" to send a message to the queue in *RabbitMQ*. Whenever I try to run this file I receive a "pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError". I do not have *RabbitMQ* installed and cannot use it for this project. I have another device that has *RabbitMQ* installed that has to receive the message I send to queue by running a "receive.py" file. I have been informed that I need a "AMQP Library" installed but I already have "pika" installed. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/file/send.py", line 6, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Here is my code for send.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='username', password='password')

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='ipaddress', credentials=credentials))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='Hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='Hello', body='Hey!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!' ")
connection.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718163/program-running-pika-throwing-amqpconnectionerror

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my macos the reseason was not installed rabbitmq . I resolved using that below commands .

In linux:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

In macos:

```
brew update
brew install rabbitmq
```

Finnaly you need to start .

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```